# ToolTip on TabItem: Show on header, but not on content

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip, tabcontrol, tabitem

Tooltips on a TabControl's TabItems are not only spawn on the TabItem's header, but also on any TabItem content which doesn't explicitly set its own ToolTip.

Here is an example, which reproduces the problem:

```
<Window x:Class="TestToolTipsOnTabControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Tab1"
                     ToolTip="Tooltip of tab1">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content of tab1 with its own tooltip" 
                               ToolTip="Tooltip on content of tab1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="more content of tab1" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab2"
                     ToolTipService.ToolTip="Tooltip of tab2">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content of tab2 with its own tooltip"
                               ToolTipService.ToolTip="Tooltip on content of tab2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="more content of tab2" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab3">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content of tab3" />
                    <TextBlock Text="more content of tab3" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Moving the mouse pointer over the "more content of tab1" text will display the ToolTip which I'd like to **only** show up on the TabItem header.

Is there any way to for the ToolTip to show up only on the TabItem header, but nowhere else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there any way to for the ToolTip to show up only on the TabItem header, but nowhere else?

You should only apply `Tooltip` to the `Header` not the whole `TabItem` so change it to:

```
           <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Tab1" 
                     ToolTip="Tooltip of tab1"/>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content of tab1 with its own tooltip" 
                               ToolTip="Tooltip on content of tab1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="more content of tab1" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is definitely the way to go. My actual application is way more complex than the example I posted here: I am setting the ToolTip by means of a style, which yields different ToolTips depending if the TabItem is enabled or disabled, for which I had to include a `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"` in the propietary ControlTemplate for the TabItems, etc... I got so confused about the mess in my code, that I missed the obvious. I am now applying the style on the TextBlock used as Header and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below piece of code to the textblocks

ToolTip="", ToolTipSevice.ShowDuration="0"

Comment: Nice try, but there is an empty ToolTip at a time.

Comment: Thanks. But the actual application has lots of content on the TabItems, most of it are UserControls deployed elsewhere too. So this would be very cumbersome to apply to all of them.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me when adding tabItems dynamically:

```
TabItem nt = new TabItem
string _newTabItemText = "xxxx" // Dynamic header text
string _newTabItemTooltip = "xxxx Tooltip" // Dynamic tooltip text
string _newTabItemName = "xxxx" // tabItem name to reference the tab item in code ie XAML x:name = "xxxx"
{
  Header = new TextBlock() { Text = _newTabItemText, ToolTip = _newTabItemTooltip },
  Name = _newTabItemName,
  Width = 108
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I can offer is this: created a `Style` for `ToolTip` with zero `Width` and `Height`:

```
<Style x:Key="NullToolTip" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>
```

When created `ToolTip` with this `Style` and placed in `Resources`:

```
<ToolTip x:Key="NoToolTip" Style="{StaticResource NullToolTip}" />
```

And assign to control that want to turn off the `ToolTip`:

```
<TabItem Header="Tab1" ToolTip="Tooltip of tab1">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Content of tab1 with its own tooltip" ToolTip="Tooltip on content of tab1"/>

        <TextBlock Text="more content of tab1" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{StaticResource NoToolTip}" />
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
```

*Note:* Similar problem appears when you use the `ToolTip` for `TreeViewItem`. His children inherit parent `ToolTip`.

Comment: Thanks. But the actual application has lots of content on the TabItems, most of it are UserControls deployed elsewhere too. So this would be very cumbersome to apply to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is running into this issue when creating the tabs dynamically, the following code did the magic:

```
        TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
        var stackPanel = new StackPanel();

        var stackPanelToolTip = new System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip();
        stackPanelToolTip.Content = "ToolTip content";
        stackPanel.ToolTip = (stackPanelToolTip);

        tabItem.Header = stackPanel;
```

So the key here was to add the tooltip to the tab header, but not to the tab element (adding it to the header means that you will have the tooltip visible only when mouse is hover the tab).